# exporting function return value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a code below

```
function createRoom(){

  $(document).keyup(function(event) {
      if ($("#room_name").is(":focus") && event.key == "Enter") {
        var plainText = document.querySelector(".create-room-class").value;
        var createRoomName = plainText.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "");
        createRoomName = createRoomName.replace(/ +/g, "");
        createRoomName = createRoomName.trim();
        if(createRoomName.length == 0){
            alert("empty");
        } else if(createRoomName.length < 5){
            alert("Room name must be equal or longer than 5 characters");
        } else if(!createRoomName.length == 0)
        {
          getCreatedRoomName(createRoomName);
          window.location = createRoomName;
        }
      }
  });

}

createRoom();

function getCreatedRoomName(x){
  return x;
}
```

What it does is first checks if input field is not empty and if not smaller than 5 characters. If everything is fine then we pass that value to a function and then redirect to that created name url. Look below.

```
  getCreatedRoomName(createRoomName);
  window.location = createRoomName;
```

And we return value (return x)

```
function getCreatedRoomName(x){
  return x;
}
```

How can I retrieve that returned value in nodejs? I tried modules it doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: You need to send `x` to the server using AJAX.

Comment: I forgot to mention that value must be read from another html page

Comment: The above code runs on the client. Node.js runs on the server. The client uses AJAX to send data to the server.